# Allow user-defined methods to be either async or sync

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I have these typescript method signatures:

```
  onPinnedError?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType;
  async onPinnedError?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType;

  onPinnedUnhandledRejection?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType;
  async onPinnedUnhandledRejection?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType;

  onPinnedUncaughtException?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType;
  async onPinnedUncaughtException?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType;
```

I was trying to tell the TS compiler that the implementor can implement a sync or async function, they have the choice, however I am not sure if it's possible with TS to tell the compiler than an async implementation is optional -

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions do two things: make the function return a promise, and allow the `await` keyword. Only the former matters to the type definition of the function, so you can allow both `async` and regular functions by changing the return type to `HookReturnType | Promise<HookReturnType>`.

For example:

```
onPinnedError?(info: HavenInfo, req: Request, res: Response): HookReturnType | Promise<HookReturnType>;
```